# Model manager and model methods for a get query

Tags: python, django, model, django-managers

I have a model `customer`. I also have a model manager for that, and i have added a class `QuerySet` that have certain methods. `add_meta()`

When i use Customers.objects.filter().add_meta() i tend to get all the meta information for the each instance. 
but when i use `Customer.objects.get(pk=1)` i can not use that `meta_data()` method with that.

here is my code.

### Reusable manager

```
class CustomerManager(models.Manager):
    """A re-usable Manager to access a custom QuerySet"""

    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
```

### MODEL

```
class Project(models.Model):
    objects = ProjectManager()

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):

        def add_meta(self):
            return self.extra(
                select={"priority": "COALESCE(bm_rank, sales_rank, created_at)",
                        "size": "order_size_price*order_size_weight",
                        "revenue": "current_selling_price*order_size_weight"
                },
                order_by=["priority"])
```

### Tried the following

```
Project.objects.filter(pk=5).add_meta().get().size
```

### That didnt work

```
Project.objects.get(pk=5).add_meta()
```

Can anyone have an idea how i can still use `add_meta` with get and with this existing code.

Comment: `models.Manager.get()` returns a model instance, not a queryset. Also, "doesn't work" is the least useful description of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add properties to your model class, as your meta information involves just some simple calculations:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # your fields....


    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.order_size_price * self.order_size_weight


# now this should work for every Project instance:
project = Project.objects.get(pk=1)
print project.size
```

If you need to do some filtering on these "calculated" attributes you may still use your extra selects...

Comment: Ahh thank you so much i think i was looking for property and was not clicking in my mind thank you.

Comment: But this wont work? `projects = Project.objects.filter(name__icontains='steve')`
`projects[1].size`??

Comment: What does it mean it won't work? What kind of exception you're getting?

Comment: actually it does work thank you. i restarted the system and worked. before it wasnt.